# How to use regex in required_if value in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, laravel-4

I have 2 field say `var1` and `var2`. both are text fields what I want if var2 contains a word `__tocken_` then field `var1` is required.

I tried this but it is not working,

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['var1' => 'required_if:var2,regex:/__tocken_/']
    //['var2' => ['required', 'regex:/__tocken_/']] //<--Regex is working fine here
);
```

So what I'm doing right now I'm setting a 3rd variable `var3` and on form submit I'm doing a JS validation if `var2` contains a word with pattern `__tocken_` then I'm setting `var3` as **`1`** otherwise **`0`**. And the validation rule is

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['var1' => 'required_if:var3,1'] //working fine
);
```

So my question is it possible to have regex **NOT the exact value** in `required_if` validation rule?

*Sample possible value for `var2`*

- Hi  `__FIRST_NAME__`, lorem ispam `__tocken_Ur1vG6xK__`.
- lorem ispam `__tocken_456vG6xK__` lorem `__tocken_T57kq6xK__`
- lorem ispam.. *so on*

Comment: perhaps you're in need of [custom validator](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: @BagusTesa: Yes I can do it with custom validation, but I was looking for more inbuilt method.

Comment: I think you should work on validation rules for `var2` as such: `['var2' => 'sometimes|regex:/__tocken_/|required_with:var1']`

Comment: thanks @revo; for your suggestion, `var2` is fully optional, only if it has a above mention pattern then `var1` is needed. So I was adding validations to `var1`. Moreover I cannot able to make your suggestion to working.

Comment: Since it would be optional you have to use `sometimes` rule. If it has a value then it should contain `__tocken_` to make `var1` a required field as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

```
$validator->sometimes('var2', 'required', function ($input) {
    return (bool) preg_match('/__tocken_/', $input->var1);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I could not able to make it work.